What is the difference between request.GET.get('username') and request.META.get('HTTP_X_ USERNAME') in DRF
I want to know the difference between this two methods of getting data
Just tried to figure it out for the object concepts of this data fetching...
I saw request.GET.get('username') used in customauth.py at the time of custom authentication and request.META.get('HTTP_X_ USERNAME') saw in DRF documentation where the custom authentication example is given.

In Django, both request.GET.get('username') and request.META.get('HTTP_X_USERNAME') can be used to retrieve data from incoming requests, but they serve different purposes depending on where the data is located in the request.
1. request.GET.get('username')
This method is used to retrieve query parameters from the URL in a GET request. For example, if you have a URL like:
/api/login?username=johndoe

You can use request.GET.get('username') to retrieve the value of the username parameter ('johndoe' in this case). This is commonly used when passing data through the query string in GET requests.
Example:
username = request.GET.get('username')

2. request.META.get('HTTP_X_USERNAME')
This method is used to access HTTP headers that are sent along with the request. Django stores HTTP headers in the request.META dictionary, and custom headers are prefixed with HTTP_. So, if a request contains a header like:
X-USERNAME: johndoe

You can retrieve it using:
username = request.META.get('HTTP_X_USERNAME')

This is typically used in scenarios such as custom authentication where sensitive data (like tokens, API keys, or custom identifiers) is passed in HTTP headers, rather than exposing it in the URL.
When to Use Each:

Use request.GET.get('username') if the client is passing data via query parameters in the URL.
Use request.META.get('HTTP_X_USERNAME') if the client is passing data via HTTP headers, which is more common in cases like API authentication.

Example of Custom Authentication with request.META:
The Django REST Framework (DRF) example you're referring to likely shows how to implement authentication using custom headers, such as passing a token or username via the X-USERNAME header.
class CustomAuthentication(BaseAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        username = request.META.get('HTTP_X_USERNAME')
        if not username:
            return None
        # Logic to authenticate user using the username

This method is generally more secure than passing sensitive information in URLs.
